# Why MySQL LONGTEXT column isn't storing string > 65.5 KB?

Tags: mysql, longtext

I have created one table. This table has a column with LONGTEXT Data Type. As per MySQL documentation LONGTEXT stores data upto 4 GB. But whenever I tried to store data which is greater than 64 KB, it is truncating the data. It stores only 64 KB data, after that it truncates remaining data. I am storing string data.

The encoding is UTF-8 and collation is UTF8-general_ci. My MySQL version is 5.6.

Comment: How do you know it is truncating the data ?

Comment: I have a file which has more than 1 MB text data. Whenever I tried to paste this data into that column it gives me error like this "Text Truncation"

Comment: you are using PHPMyAdmin ? It has its own limitations in terms of text that can be seen or posted. Use command line to check

Comment: This is coming from the place where you paste this data and not the database itself

Comment: Please check the data which you are inserting, sometimes if data is not proper then data gets truncated.

Comment: Verify that you have no casting to `text` somewhere and that your column is really `longtext`. 64k is the `text` limit, and if you actually get a truncation warning from MySQL, more data seems to be reaching MySQL. If you need help verifying that, add the query you use and the exact error/warning message you get.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I am writing simple insert query. I am using mysql workbench.

Comment: @Solarflare How to check the casting? I am writing simple insert query. INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) values ("data which is greater than 65.5 KB")

Comment: If this is the actual query you are using, then there is no casting. Can you add the actual warning message you get? Have you verified the column type with `show create table table_name`? How do you execute this query? Currently, you are implying (by not mentioning a different tool) that you are doing this in the MySQL client or MySQL workbench or maybe phpmyadmin; if not, you need to add this information.

Comment: @solarflare I have checked the column type and it is longtext. I am running this simple insert query using mysql workbench

Comment: Well, then this should work. Unfortunately, you are too vague in your question to tell you what you are doing wrong, and you still even haven't added the error message that might tell us more (and if the problem we are hunting here might be at a different place). Unless you provide a reproducible sample (your table and an insert that fails) on e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk, we probably cannot help you.